# Filter InfluxDB data before they arrive

Tags: influxdb, telegraf, telegraf-plugins

Folks,
I am storing for 7 days temperature messuremnts I do get get via MQTT via the Telegraf into a messurement on my RapsberyyPI InfluxDB. what I do see when I visualize my Temperature that I do get Temperature values in between -200 and +200 which seems to be random. So most of the time I do get the right value. Just wonder if there is a way to tell telegraf only accept values in beween -30 and +40 so I can filter these values before I insert them into my Influx DB. Any ideas?
The source of the data is c
omming from aRTL_433 sniffer running on my Rapsi and sending whatever it got as JSON. Looks like that data is not always as accurate as I do need it.

Answer (score 2):

You could try creating a continuous query that only accepts values in your range. To do this you'd need to have two measurements in your database, I'm going to call them raw_temp and temp. Maybe something like:

```
    CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY "temp_filter" ON "my_db"
    RESAMPLE EVERY 30s FOR 30s
    BEGIN
    SELECT "temperature" INTO "temp" from "raw_temp" where "temperature" > -40 and 
    "temperature" < 40 GROUP BY *
    END
```

And then create a continuous query that deletes anything in raw_temp that is older than an hour. Or you could install Kapacitor which makes it pretty easy to do data manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

use kapacitor to resolve this.

first create a database with short retention policy to store raw data.
second step, create *tick* DSL script to get what you want  and then write it back to a new database like

```
batch
   |query('''
       ...
   ''')
       .period(5m)
       .every(5m)
       .groupBy(time(1m))
    |influxDBOut()
        .database('some_database')
        .retentionPolicy('autogen')
        .measurement('some_measurement')
```